# How to add renderplot code to this below code?

Tags: r, database, shiny, visualization

The dataset I have chosen is the "Global Terrorism Database" from the University of Maryland. This dataset contains information on terror attacks around the world from 1970-2017.

The link to the dataset

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ecodan/global-terrorism-db/code

This is the code of a shiny app with data table. I want to add plots to visualize the relevent question

Can you help me add the code for the plots?

The R-Shiny code for answering these business questions is as follows:

```
library(shiny)

library(DT)

library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv("globalterrorismdb.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
               na.strings = c("NA", "NaN", "", " "))

ui <- fluidPage(

 titlePanel("Global Terrorism Database"),
 
 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     selectInput(inputId = "question",
                 label = "Select a question:",
                 choices = c("1) What are the top 5 countries with the most terrorist attacks?",
                             "2) What are the top 5 countries with the most fatalities from terrorist attacks?",
                             "3) What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most attacks?",
                             "4) What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most fatalities?",
                             "5) What is the most common type of terrorist attack?",
                             "6) What is the most common target of a terrorist attack?"))),
   
   mainPanel(
     DT::dataTableOutput("table")
   )))

server <- function(input, output) {
 
 output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
   
   if (input$question == "1) What are the top 5 countries with the most terrorist attacks?") {
     data %>%
       group_by(country_txt) %>%
       summarise(n = n()) %>%
       top_n(5, n)
   }
   
   else if (input$question == "2) What are the top 5 countries with the most fatalities from terrorist attacks?") {
     data %>%
       group_by(country_txt) %>%
       summarise(n = sum(nkill)) %>%
       top_n(5, n)
   }
   
   else if (input$question == "3) What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most attacks?") {
     data %>%
       group_by(gname) %>%
       summarise(n = n()) %>%
       top_n(5, n)
   }
   
   else if (input$question == "4) What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most fatalities?") {
     data %>%
       group_by(gname) %>%
       summarise(n = sum(nkill)) %>%
       top_n(5, n)
   }
   
   else if (input$question == "5) What is the most common type of terrorist attack?") {
     data %>%
       group_by(attacktype1_txt) %>%
       summarise(n = n()) %>%
       top_n(1, n)
   }
   
   else if (input$question == "6) What is the most common target of a terrorist attack?") {
     data %>%
       group_by(targtype1_txt) %>%
       summarise(n = n()) %>%
       top_n(1, n)
   }
   
 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to make a visualization for the questions with reactive datatable and plots, but idk how to do it. i

The business questions I have chosen are:

1. What are the top 5 countries with the most terrorist attacks?
2. What are the top 5 countries with the most fatalities from terrorist attacks?
3. What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most attacks?
4. What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most fatalities?
5. What is the most common type of terrorist attack?
6. What is the most common target of a terrorist attack?

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question? SO users can't create plots for you from scratch. Can you post any code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0):

i would pull the code to generate the answers out of the renderTable statement and into its own reactive statement. It makes it easier to see what actualy is happening and you could reuse the date somewhere else to if needed. I also added the retun statements as well. They are theoreticly not needed but makes the code easier to read.

```
library(shiny)

library(DT)

library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv("globalterrorismdb_0617dist.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                 na.strings = c("NA", "NaN", "", " "))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Global Terrorism Database"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "question",
                  label = "Select a question:",
                  choices = c("1) What are the top 5 countries with the most terrorist attacks?",
                              "2) What are the top 5 countries with the most fatalities from terrorist attacks?",
                              "3) What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most attacks?",
                              "4) What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most fatalities?",
                              "5) What is the most common type of terrorist attack?",
                              "6) What is the most common target of a terrorist attack?"))),
    
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  selected_data <- reactive({
    if (input$question == "1) What are the top 5 countries with the most terrorist attacks?") {
      data %>%
        group_by(country_txt) %>%
        summarise(n = n()) %>%
        top_n(5, n) %>% 
        return()
    }
    
    else if (input$question == "2) What are the top 5 countries with the most fatalities from terrorist attacks?") {
      data %>%
        group_by(country_txt) %>%
        summarise(n = sum(nkill)) %>%
        top_n(5, n) %>% 
        return()
    }
    
    else if (input$question == "3) What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most attacks?") {
      data %>%
        group_by(gname) %>%
        summarise(n = n()) %>%
        top_n(5, n) %>% 
        return()
    }
    
    else if (input$question == "4) What are the top 5 terrorist organizations responsible for the most fatalities?") {
      data %>%
        group_by(gname) %>%
        summarise(n = sum(nkill)) %>%
        top_n(5, n) %>% 
        return()
    }
    
    else if (input$question == "5) What is the most common type of terrorist attack?") {
      data %>%
        group_by(attacktype1_txt) %>%
        summarise(n = n()) %>%
        top_n(1, n) %>% 
        return()
    }
    
    else if (input$question == "6) What is the most common target of a terrorist attack?") {
      data %>%
        group_by(targtype1_txt) %>%
        summarise(n = n()) %>%
        top_n(1, n)
    }
  })
  
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    selected_data()
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!!